# How to disable other character input in a Numeric TextInput in React native-IOS?

Tags: android, ios, react-native, textinput

I like to disable all other character input  except numbers in TextInput. I tried lot of examples in SO but all those examples only works for android but not working on iOS. Below are the examples I tried.

```
 export default class App extends Component<Props> {
      onChange(text) {
        let newText = '';
        let numbers = '0123456789';

        for (var i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
          if (numbers.indexOf(text[i]) > -1) {
        newText = newText + text[i];
      }
    }
    this.setState({ data: { code: newText }})
  }
  state = {
    data: {
      code: '',
      phoneNo: '',
      otp: ''
    }
  }
  render() {
    const data = { ...this.state.data }
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>

        <TextInput
          onChangeText={(value) => {
            value = value.replace(/[^0-9]/g, "")
            this.onChange(value)

          }
          }
          placeholder='phone number'
          value={data.code}
          keyboard='phone-pad' />

        <Text style={styles.instructions}>
          {data.code}
        </Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

This code works fine in android ,but when I run this on iOS I can still input other characters rather than numbers. But when I console the log the state variable only has numeric value . ie,

- If I enter `+()'.` this will shows on the textinput but state variable value will be nothing.
- If I enter a number next to above input suppose 9. then Text Input
  replace every thing and only shows 9.
- Again if I put `+(){}` after 9 .the TextInput shows `9+(){}` but
  state variable has only 9 as value.

So my question is how can I avoid other character input in TextInput when I runs on iOS. (Please not that I don't have this problem in android when I run this code in android)

Comment: Did you check it on a real iphone device? Sometimes the simulator is not the best solution :)

Comment: Yes . I do. In both cases the TextInput showing other character. It does't replacing. But it replace when ever I input a number.

Comment: It looks that it is an issue in React-native. Even if you pass a hardcoded string as a value, or if you don't pass a `value` property it always displays whatever you type from the keyboard. But I see that you are passing `keyboard` property which is wrong. The correct property is `keyboardType`. Then it always will appear the number keyboard ;)